# send UserName and Password with POST request Using Inno Setup

Tags: http, authentication, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to make an HTTP POST authentication basic request using Inno Setup script.

**My Effort:**

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  ReqContent: String;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
    begin
      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      WinHttpReq.Open('POST', '<http://www.xxxx.com>', false);
      WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    ReqContent = {
    "UserName":"xxx", 
    "Password":"abcd"
    }

    WinHttpReq.Send(ReqContent);
    end;
end;
```

So, How to send **UserName** and **Password** with `POST` request?

Comment: Have u tried with the WinHttpReq.SetCredentials( "User Name",                             "Password",                    HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER);

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I tried, but unknown identifier "HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER"

Comment: Try with WinHttpReq.SetCredentials( "User Name", "Password", 0); 0 is for HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER